# Angular 2+ iframe video player click event

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, html5-video

I have this iframe which plays a video upon load:

```
<section>
  <div class="row" >
    <div style="padding-top: 56.25%">
      <iframe
        src="https://players.brightcove.net...&autoplay&muted&allowfullscreen&webkitallowfullscreen&loop&fullscreen"
        allowfullscreen
        webkitallowfullscreen
        mozallowfullscreen
        allow="encrypted-media"
        style="
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          right: 0px;
          bottom: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        "
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want to run a function once a click event happens on the video. Basically I want to navigate away from this component when someone clicks on the video (this video plays as part of a screen saver). How can I write the component properly?

The problem is since a video is playing in the iframe none of the events on the outer divs would work. Upon click it just pauses/plays the video.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution: overlay a div on top of it which handles the onclick event

```
<section>
  <div class="row" >
    <div style="padding-top: 56.25%">
      <iframe
  src="https://players.brightcove.net...&autoplay&muted&allowfullscreen&webkitallowfullscreen&loop&fullscreen"
        allowfullscreen
        webkitallowfullscreen
        mozallowfullscreen
        allow="encrypted-media"
        style="
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          right: 0px;
          bottom: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        "
      ></iframe>
      <div style="
          z-index: 1;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          right: 0px;
          bottom: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        "
        (click)="doTheThing()"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thankfully you're fullscreen, since making sure the overlay is on top would be a pain otherwise. If the source was also served by you, you could directly access the iframe's contentDocument.body and add an event listener to that.

Comment: Hi Donald, thanks for the response. Is there any other way to go about this? There is "full screen" toggle on the video and users might need to click on that. This way the whole page (and the video controls) gets unclickable.

Comment: @EfronA. You need to detect if you're in full screen mode or not, then use an IF/ELSE to change the depth `z-index` of the overlay (_eg:_ a value of `-1` puts it on the bottom layer under everything else on your page) as needed.